# Adding a new character each line C#

Tags: c#

I need to request a word from the user and then write it **in separate lines** such as:

```
w
wo
wor
word
```

First time asking for help here. I have been trying for an hour now.

EDIT:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word:");

string word;
word = Console.ReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(word[i]);
}
```

Comment: can you show what you tried and where it didn't work

Comment: [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user7673816: And how does your code's output differ from the desired output?  What still needs to be done to correct it?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [`string.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You will either need another loop around your current one or make use of the `String.Substring(int,int)` function.

Comment: At the moment it prints the word char by char in separate lines. How it should be is, it should add a new char every new line. Until the submitted word is fully constructed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're close, but as you can see, with each iteration of your loop, you are only writing a single letter at index `i` in the word.

What you need to do (as one simple solution) is create another string that you 'build up' and print out with each loop iteration:

```
string builder = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
     builder += word[i];
     Console.WriteLine(builder);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: +1 for a nice, simple answer that is direct and to the point and uses as much of the OP's original code as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Substring` to solve your problem:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word:");

string word = Console.ReadLine();
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word.Substring(0, i+1));
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Em3LnF)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it using LINQ:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word:");
string word = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
word.Select((c, i) => word.Substring(0, i + 1))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but the OP has been struggling with just creating the basic algorithm, so I think throwing a bunch of LINQ at him/her with no explanation of what each thing does is only going to cause more confusion.